# Display: None; prevents field in from being submitted while visibility:hidden allows the element to take up space

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I'm trying to make an input field for "DeliveryCharge" which is greyed out that cannot be typed in. To fill it in, the user has to click on the "Compute" button beside it to do the calculations.

```
                <div>
                    <label asp-for="DeliveryCharge" class="w-100">DeliveryCharge:</label>
                    <div style="display:flex;">
                        <input readonly asp-for="DeliveryCharge" type="number" step="0.01" style="flex-grow; width:100%;" id="deliveryChargeInput" />
                        <input asp-for="DeliveryCharge" type="number" step="0.01" style="visibility:hidden; width:0%; id="deliveryChargeHiddenInput" />

                        <button type="button" onclick="calculateDeliveryCharge()">compute</button>
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="DeliveryCharge" class="text-danger" id="deliveryChargeDanger"></span>
                </div>
```

Because of how disabled fields won't be submitted, I had to make a hidden field that holds the same value that actually is able to be submitted.
...This brings me to my main issue again,`display:none` seems like it does exactly what I want, but it also prevents hidden field from being submitted. I also can't do `visibility:none` because although it does submit, it takes up space in the form....

I also tried doing

```
                    <input asp-for="DeliveryCharge" type="hidden" class="w-100" value="USD" />
```

but that would mean that ASP.net would take the field as a string and bind a string into the property in my model that is of type `decimal`

Comment: `display:none seems like it does exactly what I want, but it also prevents hidden field from being submitted` this is not the case. So long as the input is included in the HTML of the form correctly, its value will be sent in the request

Comment: You're right, seems like I did something wrong somewhere when I tried doing that. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the read only form field a name, it will be included as part of the submitted form data. And at the same time it also becomes easier to refer to the form field.

```js
document.forms.form01.calculateDeliveryCharge.addEventListener('click', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  // give the input element a value
  form.deliveryChargeInput.value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
});

/* this eventlistener is just for showing
   that the value will be submitted */
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log([...data]);
});
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <label asp-for="DeliveryCharge" class="w-100">DeliveryCharge:</label>
  <div style="display:flex;">
    <input readonly asp-for="DeliveryCharge" type="number" step="0.01" style="flex-grow; width:100%;" name="deliveryChargeInput" />
    <button name="calculateDeliveryCharge" type="button">compute</button>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh, that's really helpful now it eliminates the need for a hidden input in the first place, I didn't know about that readonly attribute. Thanks a lot!